# Which procedures or devices do ensure the aircraft stop flying after the pilot has ejected?

Tags: safety, military, ejection-seat

Pilots eject from aircraft when it cannot be controlled any more. Ejection seems to happen without delay and few time to secure the aircraft and its weapons.

[image]
<sup>Pilot ejection, [source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/347129083752387380/).</sup>

Thanks to @RonBeyer for pointing out the [Cornfield Bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornfield_Bomber) which also links to a [notable accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1989_Belgian_MiG-23_crash) in 1989 with a MiG-23 flying 900 km and several countries, uncontrolled:

> During takeoff [from Poland], the afterburner failed and the engine
>   began losing power. At an altitude of 150 meters and descending, the
>   pilot assumed he had a complete engine failure and ejected. [...]
>   After flying over 900 km (560 mi) the MiG crashed into a house,
>   killing a Belgian teenager.

What are the procedures or features in place to prevent the aircraft to keep flying and explosives to explode?

Comment: Related: [Cornfield Bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornfield_Bomber)

Comment: I don't believe there is a mechanism for this. The aircraft *will* crash (and possibly explode), the ordinance typically will not (shouldn't be armed until after launch), which is why a lot of ejecting pilots are commended with their ability to "direct the aircraft away from people" before ejecting.

Comment: *Is it realistic to imagine the aircraft continuing to fly without pilots?* The pilot is generally ejecting because the aircraft is no longer able to fly **with** a pilot, how could it then fly without?

Comment: Devices? Does the ground count?

Comment: I did say generally :) So the question is about the scenario where a pilot ejects unnecessarily. I'd hope this is extremely rare though as that incident proves, it is possible. I think the thought of ejection and having to explain millions of dollars going up in flames to your boss will keep it a rare event.

Comment: @Notts90: You could say the same for many things on aviation, it should be rare, but we add security nonetheless, e.g. to prevent raising landing gear on the ground. What is the cost of the safety device compared to the cost of damages? In addition here we are talking about (civilian) lives.

Comment: @mins I agree that the attention to edge cases is what gives aviation such good safety records. However the aircraft will stop flying eventually, even if from lack of fuel. I think the far more important issue is **where** it stops.

Comment: This archived page has pictures of the f-106 after its landing in Montana.https://web.archive.org/web/20110106092409/http://www.f-106deltadart.com/71fis_PilotlessLanding_580787.htm

Comment: That's an impressive feat for an 1898-era aircraft, with or without pilot.

Comment: @vasin1987: Before Ron Beyer's edit, the post claimed that the MiG incident took place in 1898.

Answer (score 6):

As you pointed out, the only reason for abandoning an aircraft is because the pilot can no longer control it or successfully land it.  With or without flight crew onboard, it's going down in one form or another.  As such it's pointless to design any additional system to disable or destroy the aircraft as it accomplishes nothing.

Pilots however have been known to direct a stricken or otherwise doomed aircraft away from populated areas, as this Thunderbirds pilot did at a 2003 air show at Mountain Home AFB, in Idaho.

So too was this crash of a MiG-29 at the Paris Airshow in 1989.  Mikoyan test pilot Victor Kobachev ingested a bird in his starboard engine and the jet departed controlled flight;  Kobachev fought to direct it away from the crowd line before he punched out.

Comment: @mins An aggressor just shot your wing off, how do you decide where to crash? Explode in the air and you're just raining shrapnel down over possibly miles of people, at least when it crashes it is relatively contained.

Comment: Now I have heard stories of pilots having in flight emergencies where the crew directed the aircraft away from a populated area prior to abandoning the airplane.

Comment: Here's the follow up to last year's crash by the Thunderbird after the AF Academy fly over.  Great video from the [Denver Post](http://www.denverpost.com/2016/12/14/thunderbirds-crash-cause-colorado-springs/).  Although the F-16 looks like it just landed in the field, it was totaled.

Answer (score 1):

In September 16, 2005, a Russian jet Su-27 crashed in Lithuania after running out fuel (navigation error) ([ref1](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/09/16/world/europe/russian-jet-crashes-in-lithuania.html?_r=0), [ref2](https://www.sinodefenceforum.com/russian-su27-crashes-in-lithuania.t315/)).

I cannot find the online sources after such a long time but I remember the pilot said that he used the last remaining fuel to bring the plane away from any settlements, before ejecting. The jet, indeed, crashed in the fields with no notable danger to the people.

From this looks like the pilot is responsible for discarding the plane safely, as much as this is still possible. In cases like running out of fuel might be possible.